# objectForPrimaryKey vs filtered query(to match primary key) performance, which one is faster for large data?

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm, realm-js

Here I'm giving an example

```js
class TestRealm {
    constructor(realmDB) {
        this.realmDB = realmDB;
        this.allRealm = this.realmDB.objects('Person');
    }

    query1(primary_key) {
        try {
            const response = this.allRealm.filtered(`_id == "${primary_key}"`);
            if (response.length === 0) {
                console.log('unable to find');
                return;
            }
            return response.toJSON()[0];
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    query2(primary_key) {
        try {
            const response = this.realmDB.objectForPrimaryKey('Person', `"${primary_key}"`);
            if (!response) {
                console.log('unable to find');
                return;
            }
            return response.toJSON();
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Assume after opening the realm, I'm passing the realm object to the TestRealm constructor. In this case which query is efficient for large data?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with getting the terminology lined up

This is a *query* (aka a filter) and will return a Realm Results object

```
const response = this.allRealm.filtered(`_id == "${primary_key}"`);
```

This is *NOT a query* and will return that specific object

```
const response = this.realmDB.objectForPrimaryKey('Person', `"${primary_key}"`);
```

So you're returning two different things - also `response` in the first example is a live updating Realm Results object so it has more overhead than returning the object itself.

Also note that for 'large data' the second option will be essentially unaffected by the dataset size (generally speaking)

The second example is much faster.

Comment: Hi Jay,
Thanks for reply, but I've doubt.... In 1st response i'll get realm Result object with only one realm object(because primary_key is unique) and in 2nd response i'll get only one realm object. so my question is which one is faster(object.filtered or objectForPrimaryKey ) for large data?

NOTE: In both query i'm returning after converting toJSON(), so returning object no longer realm live object.

Comment: @PrahladSinghNegi The first example *could* return lots of objects; the filter isn't aware of what its filtering, it will simply return all objects that match the filter. Whereas the second example will return one specific object ever. As mentioned in the answer, the second example is 'much faster', and the size of the dataset will not affect its performance. We've done a LOT of testing on this as our datasets are often 2Gb or larger.